# Drop-down menu keeps going up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are my functions:

```
function dropmenu() {
    $(".dropdownitem").show('slow');
}
function hidemenu() {
    $(".dropdownitem").hide('slow');
}
```

And here is my drop-down menu:

```
<div id="dropdown" class="ns" onmouseover="dropmenu()" onmouseout="hidemenu()">
    <p id="dropper">Shortcut Menu</p>
    <p class="dropdownitem">Shortcut menu item</p>
    <p class="dropdownitem">Something</p>
    <p class="dropdownitem">Seomthing else</p>
    <p class="dropdownitem">Test menu item</p>
    <p class="dropdownitem">More testing</p>
    <p class="dropdownitem">Stuff</p>
    <p class="dropdownitem">More stuff</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I mouse over and out of the Shortcut Menu, it keeps going up and down and up and down and up and down and....

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
function dropmenu() {
    $(".dropdownitem").stop.(1,1).show('slow');
}
function hidemenu() {
    $(".dropdownitem").stop(1,1).hide('slow');
}
```

Comment: Um... when I do that my menu doesn't even work anymore... it doesn't expand when I mouse over it

Comment: Never mind, your code has an extra period here" `$(".dropdownitem").stop.(1,1).show('slow');` and when I removed it it works! Thanks!

Comment: Wait, there's one problem. When I mouse over the dropped down text, it keeps flashing. ???

Answer (score 3):

elclanrs answer will fix the bouncing , another solution is to put everything in a div that is supposed to dropdown

```
<div id="dropdown" class="ns" onmouseover="dropmenu()" onmouseout="hidemenu()">
<div class="dropdownshow">
  <p id="dropper">Shortcut Menu</p>
  <p class="dropdownitem">Shortcut menu item</p>
  <p class="dropdownitem">Something</p>
  <p class="dropdownitem">Seomthing else</p>
  <p class="dropdownitem">Test menu item</p>
  <p class="dropdownitem">More testing</p>
  <p class="dropdownitem">Stuff</p>
  <p class="dropdownitem">More stuff</p>
</div>
</div>
```

then show the whole dropdown div

```
function dropmenu() {
$(".dropdownshow").show('slow');
 }
```

or

```
   $(document).on("mouseover", "div.overout" , function() {
   $(".dropdownshow").show('slow');    
     }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".dropdownshow").hide('slow');
     });
```

before you were applying animation to 7 seperate elements at the same time causing bouncing, this will only apply to 1